# Python List Exclusions

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists with info such as `var1=vara`, `var1=varb`, `var2=vara` etc. This can have lots of entries, and I print it out ok like this

```
for y in myDict:  
    print(y+"\t"+myDict[y])
```

I have another list which has exclusions in like this var2, var3 etc. This may have < 10 entries and I can print that ok like this

```
for x in myList:
    print(x)
```

Now I want to remove occurrences of key val pairs in the dictionary where the keys are the list values. I tried this

```
for x in myList:
    for y in myDict:
        if x != y: print(y+"\t"+myDict[y])
```

but on each pass through the list it lets all the others apart from the current `x  to the screen

Is there a nice python way to remove the key val pairs from the dictionary if the key exists in the list?

Comment: Aah thanks all. It all seems too obvious now - i'm not a regular python user. My method was printing things out which hadn't yet been deleted. Thanks again all of you for the prompt response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean

```
for key in myDict:
    if key not in myList:
        print(key+"\t"+myDict[key])
```

Or one of many alternatives:

```
for key in (set(myDict)-set(myList)):
    print(key+"\t"+myDict[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mySet = set(myList)
myNewDict = dict(((k, v) for k, v in myDict if k not in mySet))
```

Note that using `mySet` instead of `myList` isn't a concern unless myList has a large number of entries.